# How do I check whether a jQuery element is in the DOM?

Tags: jquery

Let's say that I define an element

```
$foo = $('#foo');
```

and then I call

```
$foo.remove()
```

from some event. My question is, how do I check whether $foo has been removed from the DOM or not? I've found that `$foo.is(':hidden')` works, but that would of course also return true if I merely called `$foo.hide()`.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (!jQuery.contains(document, $foo[0])) {
    //Element is detached
}
```

This will still work if one of the element's parents was removed (in which case the element itself will still have a parent).

Comment: doing `$foo.closest(document.documentElement)` is faster (if anyone cares http://jsperf.com/jquery-element-in-dom)

Comment: @PerroAzul: I found a _much_ faster alternative: http://jsperf.com/jquery-element-in-dom/2

Comment: For the curious, typically if there are many ways to do something in jquery, the one that most directly calls the underlying Sizzle library is the fastest. jQuery.contains = Sizzle.contains.

Comment: Slightly faster: $.contains(document, $foo[0]) - tests both elements in DOM and out: http://jsperf.com/jquery-element-in-dom/8

Comment: Is this preferred over Kushagra answer?

Comment: Performance was my immediate concern with this method, thanks for linking the benchmarks @SLaks. So it looks like `$.contains(document.documentElement, $foo.get(0))` is the fastest way.

Comment: There is a pure-DOM way to do this, which is syntactically more readable, and I imagine very similar in terms of performance:
`document.contains($foo[0])`

Comment: @SLaks it works in IE as long as you're looking for an element and not something like a text node - also `document.contains()` is what jQuery will use if it exists, and in the particular case of this question a direct call to `document.contains()` will be much faster

Comment: All this talk of performance...? The benchmarks show one method taking 15 microseconds, and another taking 0.15 microseconds. But really, who cares - you are not going to notice any difference unless you do it a hundred thousand times. And it might all change if jQuery or the JavaScript engine gets optimised.Just use whatever method reads better to you and to whoever has to maintain your code in future.

Comment: @James - or unless your website is `facebook.com` and your DOM is as deep as the core of the earth.

Comment: `$.contains` is fastest compared to `$el.closest`  and `$el.parents`, whereas `$el.parents` is the slowest.
https://jsperf.com/contains-vs-closest-cxp

Comment: Does not work.... parents() is working ..

Answer (score 25):

How about doing this:

```
$element.parents('html').length > 0
```

Comment: I think this is a lot faster

Answer (score 7):

Probably the most performative way is:

```
document.contains(node); // boolean
```

This also works with jQuery:

```
document.contains($element[0]); // var $element = $("#some-element")
document.contains(this[0]); // in contexts like $.each(), `this` is the jQ object
```

Source from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

> **Note:**
>
> - [**Internet Explorer only supports `contains()` for elements.**](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/780874/node-contains-is-incorrect)

Comment: How has anyone looked at this answer yet? Great answer +1 (I sugested a edition, thanks)

Answer (score 6):

I just realized an answer as I was typing my question: Call

```
$foo.parent()
```

If `$f00` has been removed from the DOM, then `$foo.parent().length === 0`. Otherwise, its length will be at least 1.

**[Edit: This is not entirely correct,  because a removed element can still have a parent; for instance, if you remove a `<ul>`, each of its child `<li>`s will still have a parent. Use SLaks' answer instead.**

Comment: ... unless the removed node was not an only child

Comment: @Álvaro - Why would that matter?

Comment: @patrick: Did I miss something? What can you assure if $foo.parent().length is greater than zero?

Comment: @Álvaro - the OP is testing to make sure `$foo` was removed from the DOM. If it was successfully removed, it will no longer have a parent element. Therefore `$foo.parent().length === 0` means that the removal was successful.

Comment: $foo.closest("body") would be a fix for this technique

Comment: no... consider this: `d=$('<vader>'); c=$('<luke>').appendTo(d);`
in this case `c.parent()` is `vader` but both of them are not in DOM.

Answer (score 5):

Since I'm unable to respond as a comment (too low karma I guess), here's a full reply. The fastest way is easily to unroll the jQuery check for browser support and to shave the constant factors to minimum.

As seen also here - http://jsperf.com/jquery-element-in-dom/28 - the code would look like this:

```
var isElementInDOM = (function($) {
  var docElt = document.documentElement, find,
      contains = docElt.contains ?
        function(elt) { return docElt.contains(elt); } :

        docElt.compareDocumentPosition ?
          function(elt) {
            return docElt.compareDocumentPosition(elt) & 16;
          } :
          ((find = function(elt) {
              return elt && (elt == docElt || find(elt.parentNode));
           }), function(elt) { return find(elt); });

  return function(elt) {
    return !!(elt && ((elt = elt.parent) == docElt || contains(elt)));
  };
})(jQuery);
```

This is semantically equivalent to jQuery.contains(document.documentElement, elt[0]).

Answer (score 2):

instead of iterating parents you can just get the bounding rect which is all zeros when the element is detached from dom

```
function isInDOM(element) {
    var rect=element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (rect.top || rect.bottom || rect.height || rect.width)?true:false;
}
```

if you want to handle the edge case of a zero width and height element at zero top and zero left you can double check by iterating parents till the document.body

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: Doesn't this also recognize hidden elements as "not in DOM"? e.g. an element with `display: none` has no boundingRect either

Answer (score 1):

I liked this approach.  No jQuery and no DOM search.  First find the top parent (ancestor).  Then see if that is the documentElement.

```
function ancestor(HTMLobj){
  while(HTMLobj.parentElement){HTMLobj=HTMLobj.parentElement}
  return HTMLobj;
}
function inTheDOM(obj){
  return ancestor(obj)===document.documentElement;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Perro's comment. It can also be done like this:

```
$foo.parents().last().is(document.documentElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.fn.isInDOM = function () {
   if (this.length == 1) {
      var element = this.get(0);
      var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (rect.top + rect.bottom + rect.width + rect.height + rect.left + rect.right == 0)
         return false;
      return true;
   }
   return false;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just:  `if( $('#foo').length === 0)...` ?

Comment: @stevematdavies The question is "how to test whether an element in a given jQuery object is in the DOM", not "how to test whether an element matching a given selector string is in the DOM."

Comment: @TrevorBurnham: in all fairness, re-querying using the selector that was used to create `$foo`, and checking whether the re-query matched any element, seems a viable solution to the problem in many scenarios. It may even by *quicker* than some of the other solutions because of how both jQuery and the browsers optimize certain selectors (such as by ID).

Comment: @Matt $foo might be an element in memory detached from DOM, and there might me an element with matching selector in DOM. People looking for an answer to this question probably wants to check if it's in DOM or not. Someone working in stuff like that obviously knows how to query DOM.

Answer (score -1):

```
if($foo.nodeType ){ element is node type}
```