# JQuery: Check if element exists alongside '.remove()'

Tags: jquery, exists

I know you can check if an element exists with `$('div').length`, but when an element is destroyed using `.remove()`, `.length` still reports the div exists. How can I find whether or not it actually exists?

```
if ($('div').length) { 
  alert('yes') 
} else { 
  alert('no') 
}
```

Comment: Err.. Not exactly sure what you mean. If you use `.remove()`, the element is removed from the DOM. Length reports the expected result: http://jsfiddle.net/TmPBC/

Comment: That will alert yes as long as there is a div on the page. You can use an id to test if an exact element has been removed.

Comment: $('div') was an example. I was not testing to see if there were any divs in the entire page.

Comment: For the more generic question of "how to check if an element or one of its parents was removed", see [How do I check whether a jQuery element is in the DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3086068/323407)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test whether it has a parent:

```
if ($element.parent().length) { alert('yes') }
else { alert('no') }
```

or if you have a reference to the DOM element:

```
if(element.parentNode) {
    // yes
}
```

Obviously, this only works for elements you already have a reference to.

FWIW, the element itself still exists, it is just not part of the DOM tree.

Comment: This won't work if any parent element of `$element` has been removed from the DOM.  Eg, `$element.parent().remove()`.  `$element.parent().length` is still 1, even though `$element` is not in the DOM tree.

Comment: @gilly3: Well, I assume that `.remove()` was performed on the element, as mentioned in the question. Anyway, +1 of your solution, but I think it is sufficient to look for `body` instead of `html`.

Answer (score 9):

By exists, you mean you want to see if it exists in the dom?  Check to see if "html" is an ancestor:

```
var $myDiv = $(".myDiv");
$myDiv.closest("html").length;  // returns 1
$myDiv.remove();
$myDiv.closest("html").length;  // returns 0
```

Or use `.is("html *")`.  It returns a boolean, which is handy:

```
var $myDiv = $(".myDiv");
$myDiv.is("html *"); // returns true
$myDiv.remove();
$myDiv.is("html *"); // returns false
```

Comment: If there is a difference at all, `.closest()` would be most efficient. Depending on how `.is()` is implemented, it could be almost as efficient as `.closest()`, or it could be much worse.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> if (!$foo.closest('html').length) {
>     //Element is detached
> }
> ```
>
> This will still work if one of the element's parents was removed (in which case the element itself will still have a parent).

I cite [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3086084/1444978).

Answer (score 0):

you can get the parent of element before removing the element and after the element has been removed you can check like this!

```
    var parent = $(element).parent();
    $(element).remove();

    if(parent.children(element)) {  alert('yes'); }
    else { alert('no'); }
```

of course element would be some jquery selector