# check if element is inserted on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an “exists” function for jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Is there a better way to check if the element is already inserted on page? I'm currently doing this and is working fine, but doesn't seem for me to be the best/fast way

```
$(element).closest('body').length > 0
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I doesn't need to know if my element exists, I need to know if it's on page.

Comment: @JMax this is a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's built in .has function](http://api.jquery.com/has/)  so your code should look something like:

```
$('body').has(element)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my element doesn't have an id.

Comment: Perhaps jQuery's .has() would be of more use? http://api.jquery.com/has/

Comment: and invert what I'm doing, right? like this: `$('body').has(element)`?

Comment: Yes, it works and is better for reading :) Can you edit your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(element, 'body').size() > 0
```

It will fetch for the element within the body.

Comment: You can check it working at : http://jsfiddle.net/kBFpG/

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is searching for element "body". It's not what you are looking for

```
$(element).length > 0
```

check whether an element exists

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already have _the element_ on var. I need to know if it's inserted on page or is detached.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086068/how-do-i-check-whether-a-jquery-element-is-in-the-dom

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('element-selector-here').length )
{
    // element exist
}
else 
{
    // element doesn't exist
}
```