# issue with css selector in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
if ( $( '#nonexistent' ) ) { 
console.log('test');
}
</script>
```

Question:

Actually there is no such id `#nonexistent` in my page, but why this line still runs: `console.log('test');`

Comment: Check `$('#nonexistent').length` ?

Comment: If you want to check if an element exists you need to use length

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086068/how-do-i-check-whether-a-jquery-element-is-in-the-dom

Check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$( '#nonexistent' )` returns an empty set (which is an basically an array) and empty arrays yield true in boolean context.

You need to check `$('#nonexistent').length` instead.

If you are interested about how this exactly works, read into [this sitepoint article about truthy-/falsyness in javascript](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).

You could as well use

```
// pretty jQuery-like
document.querySelector('#nonexistent')
// or a bit faster faster:
document.getElementById('nonexistent')
```

Answer (score 1):

`$( '#nonexistent' )` returns an object (jQuery object), and all objects have a truthiness of yes. You should instead use:

```
if ( $( '#nonexistent' )[0] ) { 
  console.log('test');
}
```

Or better yet, no need for jQuery at all:

```
if (document.getElementById("nonexistent")) {
  console.log("not gonna happen");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.length` member to see if it exists.

```
if ( $( '#nonexistent' ).length ) { 
    console.log('test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To test whether an element exists use the length function.

`if ( $( '#nonexistent' ).length > 0) {
    console.log('test');
}`

You don't need the `> 0` but it helps with readability.