# detecting span tag in my DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

I have seen lot of questions like this but none of them helped me
I want to see when my span tag get available in DOM, my code looks like this

```
   <span id="inviteUpdate">0</span>

    if(jQuery("#inviteUpdate").html()>0){
        alert("Element exists");
    }
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try `jQuery("#inviteUpdate").html().length`

Comment: if(jQuery('#inviteUpdate').length) { // Your span is in DOM }

Comment: @ViktorBahtev That doesn't work, jQuery objects are always truthy, even if they're empty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086068/how-do-i-check-whether-a-jquery-element-is-in-the-dom looking for this ?

Comment: @hjpotter92 didn't worked , also I got this on console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Do you need to know if the span has text or just if it exists in the DOM?

Comment: @RussellBevan just if it exist in the DOM

Comment: @Badddy then `$('#inviteUpdate').length > 0` should do the trick

Comment: @RussellBevan doesn't work

Comment: @Badddy you sure something isn't preventing your jQuery from running? Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bevanr01/jh241Lmy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  if(jQuery("#inviteUpdate").length >0){
        alert("Element exists");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="inviteUpdate">0</span>
```

check this

Comment: The clause `jQuery("#inviteUpdate")` cannot be falsy. The first part of the condition serves no purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test whether an element exists in the DOM, use `.length`:

```
if ($("#inviteUpdate").length > 0) {
    alert ("Element exists");
}
```

This is because jQuery collections can be used as arrays, returning the original DOM elements that were matched.

Answer (score 2):

You can use getElementById method. If the value is not null, it exists.

```
var span1 = document.getElementById('inviteUpdate');
if(span1 != null)
{
    alert('span exists');
}
```

works well.