# Script on scroll down javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script in javascript that load more information on page scroll down.
The problem is that when I scroll down the script is executed twice and I have the same result twice or even more.

I want to execute the script once each time I scroll down and not execute it twice or even more each time.

This is the script:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
   
        var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastid');
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && lastID != 0){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'getdata.php',
                data:'id='+lastID,
                beforeSend:function(html){
                    $('.load-more').show();
                },
                success:function(html){
                    $('.load-more').remove();
                    $('#list').append(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var counter  = 0;


 $(window).scroll(function(){

        var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastid');
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && lastID != 0 && counter < 1){
            counter++;
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'getdata.php',
                data:'id='+lastID,
                beforeSend:function(html){
                    $('.load-more').show();
                },
                success:function(html){
                     // reset counter to 0 after you get your results
                    counter = 0;
                    $('.load-more').remove();
                    $('#list').append(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but where are incrementing counter?  It is always 0 right ?

Comment: eidited sorry it does it at the top of the if block

Comment: This is cool too, if you want to allow a few calls at a time, then you could have `--counter` instead of `counter = 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).one('scroll',function(){ ...}
..
```

Explanation of "one" from jquery docs:  The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.
http://api.jquery.com/one/
Function will execute only first time you scroll, nothing will happen second time nor any subsequent time.

Comment: is lastID null ?

Comment: No lastID is not nul. With my script the script is executed twice when i scroll down so I have the same result twice. When I tried with $(window).one('scroll',function()... The script doesn't work

Comment: have you tried wraping your function and using a  counter and only executing if coutner is less then 1?

Comment: It would not work ever again and that is the problem with my solution and yours. He'd like it to work every time on scroll but once instead of twice

Comment: Yes @TimCodes what I want is exactly what KillerDeath explained

Comment: I got it, will provide another answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeout;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);  
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){

    var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastid');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && lastID != 0){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'getdata.php',
            data:'id='+lastID,
            beforeSend:function(html){
                $('.load-more').show();
            },
            success:function(html){
                $('.load-more').remove();
                $('#list').append(html);
            }
        });
    }
 }, 200);
});
```

Second execution of scroll will trigger cancelling of function delayed execution and initiate another execution which will not be cancelled by anything.

Comment: Sorry but where are you using the var timeout ? And what did you change in my code exactly ?

Comment: To prevent second execution, something triggers another scroll handler shortly after first one. I edited it now.

Comment: Why did you "unaccept" the answer after accepting it? Something wrong?

Comment: It didn't work when I scroll down  by clicking on the scroll bar it works only when I scroll with the trackpad of my laptop. But it is a good solution

Comment: Just put a little larger number such as 200 instead of 50. Updating answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could wait until the previous one is done loading before loading a new one.

```
var isLoading

$( window ).on( 'scroll', onScroll )

function onScroll() {

  if( isLoading ) return

  isLoading = true

  $.ajax({
    success: function() {

      isLoading = false

      // Add content, etc...

    }
  })

}
```

Comment: If function is executed quickly, it will still be executed twice.

Comment: @Killer Death Javascript is single threaded.  Your fiddle code always exits with isLoading = false.  My code NEVER exits with isLoading = false.  That's a huge difference.

Comment: True, but isLoading will be set to false after successful async response, it assures that a second async call is prevented before first one finishes, he wants to prevent second event handler from firing reguardless of that.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the case here: "I want to execute the script once each time I scroll down"

Comment: Your solution is pretty similar to this actually.  It also allows more than one ajax call.  The only difference between your solution and this is that this does not create any objects which is what timeouts are, this is not calling any functions like clearTimeout or setTimeout, and this is not causing any delay between the moment the user starts scrolling and when the ajax call is sent, whereas your solution forces the ajax call to hold off for 50-200 ms after the user stops scrolling.  I think it makes more sense to fire the ajax asap and then ignore scroll events until it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more test so you ignore scroll if your loader is showing

```
if (
    $(window).scrollTop() === $(document).height() - $(window).height()

    && +lastID !== 0

    // fancy way to say "Is this element in the DOM" w/ good performance
    && $.contains(document.documentElement, $('.load-more')[0])
) {

  // then load more content

}
```

*Mini-Rant*:

I changed `==` to `===` and I explicitly coerced `lastID` to a number, which also allowed changing `!=` to `!==`.

It's simply good habit to avoid automatic type coercion when it doesn't provide any obvious benefit. There is nothing inherently bad about this language feature. However, taking reasonable steps to avoid it when you can will make your code easier to understand and easier for the jit compiler to optimize. When I find something like `==` in my own code, it's appearance is self-documenting, letting me know I intentionally leveraged type coercion for a purposeful effect (other saving 1 little keystroke).

*Note*: Selected method for checking element existence came from jsPerf provided by [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) in his comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3086084/7776106).

Comment: Okay I see Thank you