# How to determine if the DOM reference of the jquery object in the variable is broken

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. put an object in a variable with jquery.

```
const $hoge = $('#hoge');
```

2. DOM is rewritten by events etc.

```
$hoge.parent().html('<div id="hoge"></div>');
```

At this step, the variable, $hoge, is dereferenced, so I can't operate on the new element.

e.g.

```
$hoge.addClass('test'); // this is invalid.
```

Is there a way to detect $hoge in this state?

I tried...

```
const $hoge = $('#hoge');
console.log($hoge === $('#hoge')); // always false
```

Comment: There's some confusion as, after step 2, `$hoge` is *not* "dereferenced* - it still exists fine, just no longer in the DOM.   Your .addClass is not "invalid" and works fine - just it applies to the out-of-DOM element in `$hoge`.   You can confirm this by adding `$("#hoge").after($hoge)` to re-insert the element(s) stored in `$hoge`.   https://jsfiddle.net/Lgpdm7ub/   This doesn't stop your question, just slightly rewords it to - is there a way to detect if `$hoge` has been removed from the DOM.

Comment: Updated fiddle to match solution: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgpdm7ub/1/

Comment: @freedomn-m
Thank you
This was exactly the answer I was looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086068/how-do-i-check-whether-a-jquery-element-is-in-the-dom